# Loading .STEP files in browser and detecting vertices, faces and edges

Tags: javascript, three.js, stl

Options for loading `.step` files in browser and visualising using `three.js`

I am trying to create a web app for loading visualisations of multiple `.step` files in a browser and then detecting faces, edges and vertices, so that  the various visualisations can be 'assembled'.

I have done a bit of work with `Three.js` (amazing library), and looks like there is no native way to load a `.step` file into `JSON` geometry.

What would be my options to still achieve this though, would I have to run every `.step` file uploaded through a 'converter' of some kind on the backend before we can see a visualisation of it on a `Three.js` canvas?

Comment: Loading `STEP` files into `three.js` was already discussed at github (see [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7125)). Since writing a loader is very complex, it's more promising to convert to `glTF` first and the load the asset. It seems this can be done with [cqparts](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7125#issuecomment-384168600).